# Вопрос по AccessibilityService в Андройд

Tags: android, accessibility

Вопрос по AccessibilityService. Метод onServiceConnected() вызывается сразу, как даю разрешение. А вот onAccessibilityEvent() не хочет вызываться. Как его вызвать, что заставит этот метод мониторить события ?

```
public class ChatsAccService extends AccessibilityService {
    private static final String TAG = "myLogs";


    @Override
    protected void onServiceConnected (){
        super.onServiceConnected();
        Log.d(TAG, "Сервис работает!");
    }


    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Метод onAccessibilityEvent запущен");

    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте вызвать метод onAccessibilityEvent() вручную там где это необходимо, например при запуске приложения или при выполнении определенного события

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).